# Pandas сравнение с нулëм

Tags: python, pandas, max, min

Как а pandas dataFrame вычислить столбец, равный максимуму между значениями имеющегося столбца и нулём ? При коде `df['new']=max(df['num_col'],0)` возникает ошибка Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Как быть? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов - создаем временный столбец из нулей и берем максимум по оси 1

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers':np.random.randint(-10,10,10)})
df['max0'] = df.assign(zero=0).max(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Другой вариант c `where()` - если в первом аргументе условие истинно (т.е. число больше 0), то остается это число, иначе заменяется на 0:

```
df['max0'] = df.numbers.where(df.numbers.gt(0), 0)
```

Еще вариант с `mask()` - почти то же самое, что предыдущий вариант, только логика наоборот - меняются на 0 те элементы, где условие в первом аргументе истинное

```
df['max0'] = df.numbers.mask(df.numbers.lt(0), 0)
```

```
   numbers  max0
0        3     3
1       -2     0
2        0     0
3        4     4
4        8     8
5        9     9
6       -1     0
7      -10     0
8        5     5
9       -7     0
```